# Python convert csv file to Json issue

Tags: python, json, csv

I am not familiar with python program ,anyone can help? Many many thanks!

```
def ConvertInputFileJsonStr(InputCsvPath):
    #### Detail Data ####
    fo = open(InputCsvPath, "r")
    ColumnValuesCSVColumns = (
    'externalDataRef', 'language','mailingListLibraryId','surveyID')
    reader = csv.DictReader(fo, ColumnValuesCSVColumns)
    ls = []
    for row in reader:
        ls.append(row)
    groups = []
    uniquekeys = []
    for k, g in groupby(ls, lambda r: (r['externalDataRef'],r['language'], r['surveyID'])):
        groups.append({
            "externalDataRef": k[0],
            "language": k[1],
            "surveyID": k[2],
            "qualtricsDetails": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['externalDataRef','language','surveyID']} for d in list(g)]
        })
        uniquekeys.append(k)
    return groups
    fo.close()
```

And it will return

```
[
  {
    "externalDataRef": "535985",
    "language": "EN",
    "qualtricsDetails": [{
      "mailingListLibraryId": "9011111111111"
    }],
    "surveyID": "123456789"
  }
]
```

but I wish to it convert to the sample below.
How can i do it?

```
[
  {
    "externalDataRef": "535985",
    "language": "EN",
    "qualtricsDetails": {
      "mailingListLibraryId": "9011111111111"
    },
    "surveyID": "123456789"
  }
]
```

Comment: 2019-11-26  15:59:19   : ERROR  global name 'd' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_return_message.py", line 223, in <module>
    PostRequestData(InputCsvPath, logFilename)
  File "get_return_message.py", line 22, in PostRequestData
    JsonList = ConvertInputFileJsonStr(InputCsvPath)
  File "get_return_message.py", line 70, in ConvertInputFileJsonStr
    "qualtricsDetails": {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['externalDataRef','language','surveyID'] for d in list(g)}
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined

Comment: there was only one parameter in qualtricsDetails    [ { "externalDataRef": "535985", "language": "EN", "qualtricsDetails": { "mailingListLibraryId": "9011111111111" }, "surveyID": "123456789" } ]   can you help ?

Comment: data content(one record):  535985,EN,9011111111111,123456789     and print(ls)   [{'surveyID': '123456789', 'mailingListLibraryId': '9011111111111', 'language': 'EN', 'externalDataRef': '535985'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the first item of the list. 
You can make it by this but it would give `list index out of range` error for empty result.

```
"qualtricsDetails": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['externalDataRef','language','surveyID']} for d in list(g)][0]
```

Comment: wow!!! it works and the result is match our met.Thanks a lot!   [
  {
    "externalDataRef": "535985",
    "language": "EN",
    "qualtricsDetails": {
      "mailingListLibraryId": "9011111111111"
    },
    "surveyID": "123456789"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only have the following 4 columns:

```
'externalDataRef', 'language', 'mailingListLibraryId', 'surveyID'
```

So you can easily reach your goal with a much simpler syntax, by changing this line:

```
"qualtricsDetails": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['externalDataRef','language','surveyID']} for d in list(g)]
    })
```

to this:

```
"qualtricsDetails": {"mailingListLibraryId": k[3]}
```

Let me know if this helps or not please.

Comment: I know what you mean and it seems easier but i dont know how to modify my code coz i used groupby function.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to modify your code? Just change your "qualtricsDetails": to my suggested version, just like you do for the other answer. Exactly the same way.